# transactions with mongoose-transaction-decorator in NestJs and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, nestjs

While in the search of how to implement `Transactions` in nestjs and mongodb, I came across a package named `mongoose-transaction-decorator`. I know the other transaction methods, but I want to implement with this package, as it might provide facility like **Spring Boot's @Transactional decorator** somehow. As in spring boot we don't have to do much stuff and just simply put a @Transactional decorator on the top of the function.

Following is the link to the github repo of the package

https://github.com/GO-DIE/mongoose-transaction-decorator

Or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transaction-decorator

**Now I'm having trouble implementing this in NestJs, if someone can help here!**